# Как посчитать сколько всего цифр (знаков) в javascript?

Tags: массивы, javascript

Как посчитать сколько всего цифр (знаков) в javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте

```
.length
```

например

```
var str = 'string';

console.log('В переменной str %s знаков', str.length);
```

Чтоб получить кол-во цифр в числе можно воспользоваться этой функцией

```
function countDigits(n) {
   for(var i = 0; n > 1; i++) {
      n /= 10;
   }
   return i;
}
```

например

```
var num = 123456;
console.log('В переменной num %s знаков', countDigits(num));
```

Comment: Ну, или можно вспомнить школьный курс математики, и написать подсчёт цифр в числе через логарифмы:

    var log10 = Math.log(10);

    function countDigits(n) {
        return Math.floor(Math.log(num) / log10) + 1;
    }

Производительность обоих вариантов примерно одинаковая (+/-1%), так что можно использовать любой.

http://jsperf.com/log-vs-division

Comment: countDigits(100) //вернет 2

Answer (score 2):

Простое решение:

```
var a = 10;
alert(String(a).length)
```

=>**edit 28.12.2017**:

```
    function isInt(n){return Number(n) === n && n % 1 === 0;}
    var isFloat=(n)=>{return Number(n) === n && n % 1 !== 0;}
    var скокСимволов=(число)=>{a=число;
     if(typeof(a)=='number'){
        var b = String(a).length;
        var b = (a<0)?b-=1:b;
        var b = (isFloat(a))?b-=1:b;
        return b
     }else{return 'идина%ер'}
    }
    cl=console.log;
    cl("Int => %s",скокСимволов(100500));//6
    cl("float => %s",скокСимволов(100.500));//4 (without 2 zeros)
    cl("int_neg => %s",скокСимволов(-11.1));//3
    cl("float_neg => %s",скокСимволов(-1.23)); //3
    cl("float_neg => %s",скокСимволов('sex')); //********
```

Comment: Проблема в числах с запятой, она засчитается, как знак

Comment: ну и отрицательные значения тоже будут не верно считать, но это быстрое решение тож имеет место быть (когда знаешь, что всегда будут целые положительные числа)

Answer (score -1):

Посчитать количество символов в числе, можно при помощи метода toLocaleString если работа идёт с большими числами, просто после преобразования убирать символы пробелов и по желанию можно удалять запятую если числа с плавающей точкой.

```
const num = 1.1111111111111112e+12;
num.toLocaleString('ru-RU') // '1 111 111 111 111,111'
num.toLocaleString('ru-RU').replace(/\s/g, '').length // 17
num.toLocaleString('ru-RU').replace(/\s|,/g, '').length // 16
```

только с отрицательными числами это работать не будет

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/728824)